# Are C++ std::array iterators guaranteed to be pointer-like?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, iterator

I have a C++ array:

```
std::array<int, 10> arr { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

I want to [reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) the last five elements, to end up with `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 }`. I know `std::array` gives me random access iterators, so I can definitely write this:

```
std::reverse(arr.begin() + 5, arr.end());
```

But, I wonder about a few other possible approaches.

`T*` is a random access iterator, so I could write this:

```
std::reverse(&arr[5], &arr[arr.size()]);
```

Which I'm *fairly* sure is well-defined, since it's permissible to reference (but not access) one-past-the-end of an array.

What I'm wondering about is whether this is allowed:

```
std::reverse(&arr[5], arr.end());
```

This runs on my machine, but that doesn't mean it's standard behavior.

If `arr` was a C-style array `T[]`, then its iterator type is obviously `T*`. But, at least at a cursory glance, I don't see any guarantees that `std::array<T, C>::iterator` is equal to `T*`, or is even comparable to it.

Does the standard guarantee that the above line of code works? Are `std::array<T, C>::iterator`s guaranteed to be compatible with pointers to `T` elements in the array?

Comment: You don't need to do that, just use `arr.begin()+5`

Comment: I know the first snippet I posted is the correct way to do this. I'm curious as to whether the alternative is allowed.

Comment: It's only correct if both your beginning and end are pointers, as in your first example.  And I believe it's undefined behavior to get a pointer from the `end()` iterator, so that's not correct either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `std::array<T, C>::iterator` is not *guaranteed* to be a raw `T*` pointer, or comparable to a raw `T*` pointer.  Nothing prevents an implementation from using a proxy type for the `iterator` (to provide debugging, bounds checking, etc), just like with any other container type.

Also, `arr[arr.size()]` is *undefined behavior* since it accesses an element that is out of bounds, so `&arr[arr.size()]` is also *undefined behavior* as you are taking the address of an element that doesn't exist.  But using `arr.begin()+arr.size()` and `&arr[0]+arr.size()` are both safe for creating a one-past-the-end iterator/pointer (as long as you don't dereference them).

Comment: Does `std::prev(arr.end(), 5)` also work?  For `std::reverse(std::prev(arr.end(), 5), arr.end());` (assuming arr.size() ≥ 5).

Comment: Yes, this would be defined behavior, as well.

Comment: I think OP would like to know `std::reverse(&arr[0] + 5, &arr[0] + arr.size());` though this might be UB if `arr` is empty.

Comment: @Eljay yes, that would be perfectly ok.

Comment: @LouisGo that is not what the OP asked. He wants to know if he can safely mix `&arr[0] + 5` with `arr.end()`, and that is not guaranteed to be ok. `std::reverse(&arr[0] + 5, &arr[0] + arr.size());` (provided `arr.size()` ≥ 5 is true) is perfectly fine.

Comment: _so `&arr[arr.size()]` is also undefined behavior as you are taking the address of an element that doesn't exist. ......... But using `arr.begin()+arr.size()` and `&arr[0]+arr.size()` are both safe for creating a one-past-the-end iterator/pointer (as long as you don't dereference them)._ -> Aren't `&arr[arr.size()]` and `&arr[0]+arr.size()` same?

Comment: `arr[arr.size()] is undefined behavior since it accesses an element`. Does it? Accessing the element would mean either reading or writing to it.

Comment: @MartinYork You are not allowed call `operator[]` with an index that is out of bounds. https://godbolt.org/z/f89bbzff4

Comment: Think about it. With a C array, `&arr[size]` is equivalent to `&(*(arr+size))`, thus the one-past-the-end pointer *may* be dereferenced, which is not allowed. The same is true for `std::array`, as`arr[size]` returns a reference to the one-past-the-end element, which is not allowed. Some may argue that `&(*(arr+size))` may optimize to just `arr+size` with no dereference. That's possible, but not guaranteed. It depends on the compiler implementation.